# Graph of $\log(3-x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, graphing-functions

So if $y=\log(3-x) = \log(-x+3)$ then you reflect $\log(x)$ in the $y$ axis to get $\log(-x)$.

Then because it is $+3$ inside brackets you then shift to the left by $3$ giving an asymptote of $x=-3$ and the graph crossing the $x$ axis at $(-4,0)$.

However this does not work. The answer shows the $+3$ in the bracket shifting the curve to the right by $3$ giving an asymptote of $x=3$ and the curve crossing the $x$ axis at $(2,0)$.

Why does it do this? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: You should do horizontal shifts **before** reflections.  You analyzed the transformations correctly but applied them in the wrong order.  In general, it works to do horizontal shifts first, then any stretching or shrinking in either direction, then reflections in either direction, then vertical shifts.  This is sometimes called the HSRV method, although these things don't typically have universal names.

Comment: thanks, got it..is there any particular reason for this order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small set of algebraic operations that correspond to geometric transformations:

When we have the graph of a function $y = f(x)$...

**Shifting:**

- The substitution $x \mapsto x - h$ shifts a graph $h$ units to the right (that'd be left, if $h$ is negative)
- The substitution $y \mapsto y - k$ shifts a graph $k$ units down (up if $k$ is negative)

**Reflecting:**

- The substitution $x \mapsto -x$ reflects the graph across the $y$-axis; a "left/right flip"
- The substitution $y \mapsto -y$ reflects the graph across the $x$-axis; an "up/down flip"

Now, here's the key thing: These transformations have to be written *exactly like this*, only replacing $x$ or $y$ with something.

---

So, when we break down $y = \ln(3 - x)$ as you have...

$$
y = \ln(x) 
    \xrightarrow{x\ \mapsto\ -x} 
y = \ln(-x) 
    \longrightarrow 
y = \ln(-x + 3)
$$

the last transformation, $-x \mapsto -x + 3$, is **not** one of our basic transformations: We are adding $3$ to $-x$, not $x$. As written, we simply can't recognize this as corresponding to any of our basic transformations. But, if we think about it a little differently...

$$
y = \ln(x) 
    \xrightarrow{{x}\ \mapsto\ -x} 
y = \ln(-\color{red}{x}) 
    \xrightarrow{\color{red}{x}\ \mapsto\ \color{red}{x - 3}}
y = \ln\bigl(-(\color{red}{x - 3})\bigr) = \ln(-x + 3)
$$

which we recognize as the sequence of transformations 1) Flip the graph left/right, and 2) Shift to the right 3 units.

There is an alternative:

$$
y = \ln(x) 
    \xrightarrow{x\ \mapsto\ x + 3} 
y = \ln(x + 3) 
    \xrightarrow{x\ \mapsto\ -x}
y = \ln(-x + 3)
$$

so we see the transformation can also be achieved by 1) Shifting the graph $3$ units left, then 2) Flipping left and right.

---

So, long story short: To recognize a graph as the transformation of another graph, you *have* to figure out how to only use substitutions like "add this to $x$", or "make $x$ negative", not adding things to $-x$, or $2x$, etc.

Comment: A good, thorough answer, but see the question comment by 'tilper'. Isn't the HSRV method more concise. Or is there a possible shortcoming in accepting it universally for all problems. What's your opinon on it?

Comment: It's definitely more concise, that's true! You did ask *why* things were breaking down, which I felt deserved a bit of verbiage :) But, generally, that order works well. If you start transforming trig functions, that's generally not the approach used -- there we generally like to write $f(bx + c)$ as $f\bigl(b(x + \frac{c}{b})\bigr)$, and think of it as "Stretch horizontally, then shift" but that's the only example I can think of where the suggested order is uncommon. Actually...

Comment: The suggested order just comes from breaking down $a \cdot f(bx + c) + d$ into those "do this to $x$ or $y$" steps. We change $x \mapsto x + c$, then $x \mapsto bx$ (so we have $f(bx + c)$ at this point), then $y \mapsto ay$ and finally $y \mapsto y + d$. If you are both stretching and shifting horizontally, it can be really strange to stretch a shifted graph (try it with $\log_2(2x + 6)$), while the $bx + c = b(x + \frac{c}{b})$ way of thinking tends to be easier (for me at least).

Comment: Just to clarify- the f(bx+c) method is shifting then stretching

Comment: ...and the f(b(x+c/b)) method is stretching then shifting. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, I tried plotting the log2(2x+6) graph, I don't understand why it is strange to plot it if you stretch it after shifting it? Could you elaborate on that point?

Comment: Yeah, you’ve got the interpretations of $f(bx + c)$ versus $f\bigl(b(x + \frac cb) \bigr)$ correct. You might find either way (or both) perfectly natural. I personally prefer the second, and find the other a bit harder/stranger to use, but perhaps it’s just me.

Answer (score 1):

Start with $y=\log(x)$. To shift this left three units, replace "$x$" with "$x+3$". Now you have $y=\log(x+3)$.

Now reflect over the $y$-axis. To do this, replace "$x$" with "$-x$". Now you have $y=\log(-x+3)$.

The order that the horizontal graph transformations happen is opposite from what you might think by the order of operations. If you first do "$x\mapsto-x$ and then do $x\mapsto x+3$, you get $\log(x)\mapsto\log(-x)\mapsto\log(-(x+3))$ which is not what you set out with.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

- $3-x$ put the origin in x=3 (right translation) and reverse axis direction
- thus the vertical asympthote is at $x=3$ and the root is at $x=2$

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on the 1st bullet point

Comment: Its not clear..

Comment: @user16701 Consider $3-x=0 \iff x=3$ thus the new origin is at $x=3$

Comment: @user16701 and the direction is reversed sin we have $-x$, from here you have all the information to plot the function

Comment: No, I understand that. I'm more interested in understanding why the standard rules don't apply to this case.

Comment: @user16701 Sorry what do ypu mean by standard rule?

Comment: Nvm, i got the answer in the question comment. Sorry if my question was unclear

Comment: @user16701 Sorry to me if I didn't catch your point! it's good that you have solved anyway! Bye